# Creating an HTML table with database values in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to display a table showing the values of three fields for each of the units in a table. Some assistance with creating the dictionary from the database and passing objects to the template would be greatly appreciated.

```
@app.route('/')
def index(row):
    unit_count = Units.query.count()
    unit = Units.query.filter_by(id=row).first()
    rows = [] # Unsure how to define rows from Units db table
    return render_template('table_overview.html', title='Overview', rows=rows, unit=unit)
```

```html
{% for row in rows %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ row.unit.idnum }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ row.unit.product_code }}</td>
    <td bgcolor="{{ row.unit.stat_colour }}">{{ row.unit.unit_status }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off your view function can't receive the `row` input you specify. If you're trying to show all rows in the table you can do it like this:

#### views.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    rows = Units.query.all()
    return render_template('table_overview.html',
                            title='Overview',
                            rows=rows)
```

#### table_overview.html (template)

```
    {% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.idnum }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ row.product_code }}</td>
        <td bgcolor="{{ row.stat_colour }}">{{ row.unit_status }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: That did it! Far simpler than I'd expected. Thanks very much for helping me, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks! It sure beats generating html in pure Python scripts ;) Flask has answered my prayers.